# Why am i getting "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am making a webrowser game and I am trying to get monsters into my data base when I get the error: 
    Subquery returns more then 1 row

here is my code

```
INSERT INTO monster_stats(monster_id,stat_id,value) 
VALUES 
( (SELECT id FROM monsters WHERE name = 'Necroborg!'),
  (SELECT id FROM stats WHERE short_name = 'atk'), 
   2);
```

any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that name is unique in a table

Comment: So there's no relationship between stats and monsters? (Didn't imagine I'd be saying that today)

Comment: there may be multiple entries with the value `Necroborg!` or `atk`. try using limit in the subqueries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use LIMIT 1

```
INSERT INTO monster_stats(monster_id,stat_id,value) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM monsters WHERE name = 'Necroborg!' LIMIT 1),(SELECT id FROM stats WHERE short_name = 'atk' LIMIT 1),2);
```

Or you could use Insert from select, with join, if you have relations with 2 tables.

```
INSERT INTO monster_stats(monster_id,stat_id,value)
(SELECT monsters.id, stats.id, 2 as value FROM monsters 
LEFT JOIN stats on monsters.id = stats.monsters_id
WHERE monsters.name = 'Necroborg!'
AND stats.short_name = 'atk'
)
```

MYSQL insert from select:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one or both of the following:

- There is more than one monster named `'Necroborg!'`.
- There is more than on stat named `'atk'`.

You need to decide what you want to do.  One option (mentioned elsewhere) is to use `limit 1` to get only one value from each statement.

A second option is to better specify the `where` clause so you get only one row from each table.

Another is to insert all combinations.  You would do this with `insert . . . select` and a `cross join`:

```
INSERT INTO monster_stats(monster_id, stat_id, value) 
    SELECT m.id, s.id, 2
    FROM (SELECT id FROM monsters WHERE name = 'Necroborg!') m CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT id FROM stats WHERE short_name = 'atk');
```

A third possibility is that there is a field connecting the two tables, such as `monster_id`.  But, based on the names of the tables, I don't think that is true.